# Not able to update UI while using Bloc architecture in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I want to update the selected user in UI in flutter. I'm using bloc to manage the state of the app. I'm not sure how to achieve it. I tried the debug print and it is showing the current selected user but it is not updating in the UI. I have also put my code here

Any ideas

```
 SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: BlocBuilder<DropdownBloc, DropdownState>(
                    builder: (context, state) {
                      if (state is DropdownInitial) {
                        BlocProvider.of<DropdownBloc>(context)
                            .add(SelectionEvent());
                      }
                      if (state is Loaded) {
                        List<String> list = state.data as List<String>;
                        String selectedValue = "Tara Wood";
                        return DropdownButton<String>(
                          value: selectedValue,
                          items: list
                              .map((data) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                  value: data, child: Text(data.toString())))
                              .toList(),
                          onChanged: (String? item) {
                            setState(() {
                              selectedValue = item!;
                              debugPrint(
                                  "This is selected value for the dropdown $selectedValue");
                            });
                            BlocProvider.of<SessionSelectionBloc>(context)
                                .add(SessionSelectedEvent(username: item!));
                          },
                        );
```

I tried to put the dropdown code in separate file however I'm not sure how can I trigger the bloc events from there. Ideally I want to create a generic dropdown because of the code reusablility

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have one variable in your Bloc and then use that variable in the UI like this :

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: BlocBuilder<DropdownBloc, DropdownState>(
                    builder: (context, state) {
                      if (state is DropdownInitial) {
                        BlocProvider.of<DropdownBloc>(context)
                            .add(SelectionEvent());
                      }
                      if (state is Loaded) {
                        List<String> list = state.data as List<String>;
                        String selectedValue = "Tara Wood";
                        return DropdownButton<String>(
                          value: BlocProvider.of<SessionSelectionBloc>(context).selectedValue, <--HERE IS THE CHANGE AND YOU NEED TO MAKE THIS VARIABLE IN BLOC
                          items: list
                              .map((data) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                  value: data, child: Text(data.toString())))
                              .toList(),
                          onChanged: (String? item) {
                            setState(() {
                              selectedValue = item!;
                              debugPrint(
                                  "This is selected value for the dropdown $selectedValue");
                            });
                            BlocProvider.of<SessionSelectionBloc>(context)
                                .add(SessionSelectedEvent(username: item!));
                          },
                        );
```

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly I'm suppose to pass that value to Bloc. I tried to put that line of code in my app. it gives me an error. 

The getter 'selectedValue' isn't defined for the type 'SessionSelectionBloc'.
Try importing the library that defines 'selectedValue', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'selectedValue'

Comment: That's what I said in my answer as well that you need to define variable named 'selectedValue' in your bloc to use it otherwise it won't be able to find that variable in that bloc.

Comment: Ok I will implement it and then I will let you 

Thanks

Comment: If it done then approve the answer and upvote it so that other can get helped as well.